# Making folder lock software by changing permissions in c

Tags: c, security, permissions, dos

I am creating a c executable file that change permissions of a folder.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dos.h>
main()
{
system("cacls foldername /e /p everyone:n");
}
```

it produces a file that should be present where the folder is located and we have to add the folder name at the time of compiling. 
but when i am doing this

```
char foldername[15];
printf("Enter the foldername");
scanf("%s",foldername);
system("cacls %s /e /p everyone:n");
```

then its not working....! please help me with this !!

Comment: When you say, "its not working....!", what do you mean, exactly?

Comment: no error in compiling but its not changing the permission of that folder.

Comment: If C++, you might look at `SetNamedSecurityInfo` to change file/folder permissions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379579(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Your call to `system()` doesn’t use `foldername` at all. You need to make the command string, then call `system()`:

```
char foldername[15];
printf("Enter the foldername");
scanf("%s", foldername);

char command[100];
sprintf(command, "cacls %s /e /p everyone:n", foldername);
system(command);
```

Of course, this code is vulnerable to buffer overflows: if the user enters more than 14 characters in their folder name, the call to `scanf()` writes outside the `foldername` buffer, causing undefined behaviour—maybe a crash, maybe not. Your question is tagged C++, where `std::string` manages safe dynamic allocation of memory for you:

```
using namespace std;

string foldername;
cout << "Enter the folder name: ";
getline(cin, foldername);

ostringstream command;
command << "cacls " << foldername << " /e /p everyone:n";
system(command.str().c_str());
```

If you are indeed using C++, I would prefer the safer approach.

Comment: And if you are indeed using C++, I would prefer the OP not forget `main`'s return type.

Comment: @l4zyw0rm: `command` is an `ostringstream`, a kind of `string` buffer to which you can write as though it were an output stream. `.str()` converts an `ostringstream` to a C++ `string`, and `.c_str()` converts a C++ `string` to a C-style `const char*`. You could get the same behaviour by saying `string command = string("cacls ") + foldername + " /e /p everyone:n"; system(command.c_str());`